# С чего стоит начать обучение Java и где читать о стандартных технологиях Java?

Tags: java

Хочу начать пробовать джаву прямо сейчас. Начать с чтения документации базовых возможностей, а потом сделать простое приложение типо бэкэнда для чата.

Решил спросить java программистов с чего начать вы бы посоветовали себе в прошлом?

Я нашел 2 ресурса
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Вроде от оракла и кажется все базовые вещи есть, но не вижу там ничего про стримы, а это базовая технология, поэтому мне кажется что этот мануал может быть устаревшим.

https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/

Типичный туториал от нонейма из интернета, но мб тут меньше деталей и особенностей описано.

Поэтому вопрос про то что бы выбрали из этого вы (или может быть что-то третье) и где в джава мире искать информацию о штуках вроде стримов? Если этой технологии нет в самой первой версии языка, значит искать нужно в описании той версии, в которой фича впервые появилась или есть какой-то список технологий с документацией? Куда мне идти в будущем, что бы прочитать о работе какой-то технологии в джаве? Например на сайте PHP в документах есть список встроенных технологий и описание зачем они нужны, есть ли что-то подобное у Java?

Вижу есть в документации https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html но там не описывается например зачем нужны стримы. А я имею в виду какой-то список где пишут что-то типо "если столкнулся с данными поступающими кусочками, то с такими данными можно работать с помощью стримов"

---

Почитал ссылку @insolor, не нашел там ничего полезного относительно моего вопроса. Я думаю что формат книги не может содержать ответ на этот вопрос, должен быть какой-то сайт, скорее всего официальная страница от оракла, где описываются технологии с описанием их назначения и целей применения, размером хотя бы в 2-3 параграфа для каждой

---

@insolor дал ссылку на пример страницы с описанием https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

Это тот тип страниц который меня интересует, осталось только выяснить где можно найти список таких страниц и это можно будет считать ответом на мой вопрос

Comment: Почитал ссылку @insolor, не нашел там ничего полезного относительно моего вопроса. Я думаю что формат книги не может содержать ответ на этот вопрос, должен быть какой-то сайт, скорее всего официальная страница от оракла, где описываются технологии с описанием их назначения и целей применения, размером хотя бы в 2-3 параграфа для каждой

Comment: Для изучения подойдет любая книга или онлайн учебник по интересующей версии Java. Если нужна дополнительная информация по конкретной теме, например, по тем же стримам, ищите именно про стримы. Какого-то централизованного сайта, где будут ответы на все вопросы жизни, вселенной и всего такого, просто не существует.

Comment: @insolor попробуй полистать сайт https://www.php.net/manual/en/ для примера. Меня интересует что-то подобное для Java. На этом сайте есть список технологий встроенных в PHP (не пользовательские библиотеки) и к каждой технологии есть описание, например: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php

Comment: java rush имеет хорошие отзывы, поищите в сторону курсов, если лень читать книги

Comment: @Игорь, хорошо, если вам нужен аналог приведенной вами ссылки, вот официальная документация по Java 8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/

Comment: @Komdosh Курсы наоборот, слишком много воды, а мне не хочется читать абстрактные описания того, как писать программы. Я уже умею программировать, мне нужно только источник знаний о Java технологиях. Как я уже сказал в вопросе, [в документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html) можно найти список технологий для конкретной версии, но там только описание API, но не говорится о том для чего эта технология, даже вкратце

Comment: "Вроде от оракла и кажется все базовые вещи есть, но не вижу там ничего про стримы, а это базовая технология, поэтому мне кажется что этот мануал может быть устаревшим." - видимо плохо искали https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Comment: @insolor о, да, вот последняя ссылка это то что меня интересует. А как ты на неё попал с страницы туториала? Можешь хотя бы примерно описать путь как попадать в такие страницы? Если это возможно и для других технологий, то это можно считать ответом

Comment: Ответ прост: запрос в поисковике "java streams"

Comment: @insolor но это не то что меня интересует. Меня интересует список технологий, которые существуют в Java и описание к ним. Я не знаю какие технологии существуют, поэтому нужен список. В документации API есть такой список, но нет описания, а я не знаю для чего нужны эти технологии. Поэтому важно как именно ты дошел до той страницы

Comment: @Игорь список https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html - это оглавление, кликаете на конкретные пакеты (java.util.stream там тоже есть) и для большинства там есть общее описание. Для тех что нету (например java.lang.annotation), просто гуглите по главным словам, в данном случае `java annotation` и первые же ссылки ведут на обзорные страницы.

Comment: @RomanKonoval кажется я нашел эту страницу через документацию. Не могу сослаться на неё, потому что там все через iframe, но теперь все в порядке.

Спасибо всем кто ответил, получается я немного не разобрался в сайте документации

Comment: Ну и опять же, выше дали ссылку на docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs. Там выбираете любой элемент, и далее Overview - по-моему, как раз то, что вы ищете.